# Comunication with object android-wfc

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I need to comunicate information between a webservice wfc soad with an android device.
I get to comunicate strings, but now I want to send objects that the web service will work with.

I followed [this tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html).

However, it doesn't work for me. I get the error below:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:DeserializationFailed' faultstring: 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:user. The InnerException message was 'Element user from namespace http://tempuri.org/ cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Seems that my webservice can deserialize my object... but why?
Also I saw that the "user" object I sent is in another namespace of the webservice, so I don't know if it could influence, if this do something, how can I correct it?

And at last, is there any method to see what xml(soad) are using in the comunications?

Thanks